# What is the practical difference between locking and deleting a user password?

Tags: passwd

The accepted answer to [How do I completely remove root password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11700690/96588) suggests `passwd -d root` ("deleting" the password), and a comment suggests instead using `passwd -l root` ("locking" the password). The only difference seems to be that a locked password can be unlocked by removing the initial "!" before it. Are there any other practical considerations, particularly related to security and disabling the root account?

Comment: Have you read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700690/how-do-i-completely-remove-root-password#comment71515177_11700775)? I believe this is one of the practical and important difference.

Comment: Oh deleting a password == setting it to the empty string? That's surprising, especially since setting an empty password is trivial. I thought it would delete the *hash* from /etc/shadow, effectively doing something similar to locking but not allowing password recovery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to `man 1 passwd`,

> -d, --delete
>
> Delete a user's password (**make it empty**). This is a quick way to disable a password for an
>     account. It will set the named account **passwordless**.

Practically, you can see the difference when you use CUI (not a terminal emulator). After you execute `passwd -d root`, you can login as root even without being prompted for the password since the password is empty. The similar thing is observed when you use `su` command (see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700690/how-do-i-completely-remove-root-password#comment71515177_11700775) for example). In contrast, after `passwd -l root`, you cannot login as root using password<sup>[1]</sup>.

So just deleting the password of root is strongly discouraged, while locking it has many advantages and that is chosen as the default setting on some environment like Ubuntu. [*RootSudo - Ubuntu Community Help Wiki*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) has much information about this.

---

<sub>[1]: Locking a password doesn't mean the user is completely disabled. You can still login using non-password authentication (e.g. SSH key or `sudo`). See `man 1 passwd` for the detail.</sub>

Comment: Again, the ambiguity of "delete" is surprising. I thought for sure someone without a password could not log in, at least on a \*nix system from the 90s onwards.

Comment: @l0b0 I agree with you. I was also confused when I first tried to understand the difference.